# Split multi-bracket data (JSON arrays) into rows preserving associations

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-14, set-returning-functions

I need to split data from bracket to row format.

If there is data in multi bracket, it does not update properly using below query.

Here's an example:

```sql
create table test (
  id integer,
  questionid character varying (255),
  questionanswer character varying (255)
);

INSERT INTO test (id,questionid,questionanswer) values
(1,'[101,102,103]','[["option_11"],["Test message 1"],["option_14"]]'),
(2,'[201]','[["option_3","option_4"]]'),
(3,'[301,302]','[["option_1","option_3"],["option_1"]]'),
(4,'[976,1791,978,1793,980,1795,982,1797]','[["option_2","option_3","option_4","option_5"],["Test message"],["option_4"],["Test message2"],["option_2"],["Test message3"],["option_2","option_3"],["Test message4"]]');
```

Query:

```sql
select t.id, t1.val, v1#>>'{}' from test t 
cross join lateral (select row_number() over (order by v.value#>>'{}') r, v.value#>>'{}' val 
   from json_array_elements(t.questionid::json) v) t1
join lateral (select row_number() over (order by 1) r, v.value val 
   from json_array_elements(t.questionanswer::json) v) t2 on t1.r = t2.r
cross join lateral json_array_elements(t2.val) v1;
```

Current query output for `id = 4`:

| id | val | ?column? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1791 | option_2 |
| 4 | 1791 | option_3 |
| 4 | 1791 | option_4 |
| 4 | 1791 | option_5 |
| 4 | 1793 | Test message |
| 4 | 1795 | option_4 |
| 4 | 1797 | Test message2 |
| 4 | 976 | option_2 |
| 4 | 978 | Test message3 |
| 4 | 980 | option_2 |
| 4 | 980 | option_3 |
| 4 | 982 | Test message4 |

Associations between questions and answers come out wrong. Output should be:

| id | val | ?column? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 976 | option_2 |
| 4 | 976 | option_3 |
| 4 | 976 | option_4 |
| 4 | 976 | option_5 |
| 4 | 1791 | Test message |
| 4 | 978 | option_4 |
| 4 | 1793 | Test message2 |
| 4 | 980 | option_2 |
| 4 | 1795 | Test message3 |
| 4 | 982 | option_2 |
| 4 | 982 | option_3 |
| 4 | 1797 | Test message4 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most importantly, use `WITH ORDINALITY` instead of `row_number()` and join unnested questions and answers on their ordinal positions. See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

And use `json_array_elements_text()`. See:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

```sql
SELECT t.id, qa.q_id
     , json_array_elements_text(qa.answers) AS answer
FROM   test t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   json_array_elements_text(t.questionid::json) WITH ORDINALITY q(q_id, ord)
   JOIN   json_array_elements(t.questionanswer::json)  WITH ORDINALITY a(answers, ord) USING (ord)
   ) qa
ORDER  BY t.id, qa.ord;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/phDMO3kx)

Aside: you should probably store JSON values as type `json` (or `jsonb`) to begin with.